# Neo4j Traverse Graph of Indefinite Length With Selection Criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of unknown length.  I need to be able to start from a node and traverse the length of the entire chain.  I am able to do this using the quantified path pattern like below

```
MATCH (:Station { name: 'Station A' })((:Station)-[:NEXT]->(:Station)){1,}(a:Station))
RETURN *
```

However, it is not enough to return all of the nodes.  At a particular node I have many NEXT relationships that point to other nodes.  The correct path to take is determined by plucking off the name property from the previous node, and comparing that to the name property on all of the relationships.  As an example:

`(:Station {name:"Station A"})-[:NEXT]->(:Station {name:"Station B"})` 
At the Station node named "Station B", I have 3 NEXT relationships

```
[:NEXT {name:"Station A}]
[:NEXT {name:"Station B}]
[:NEXT {name:"Station C}]
```

The correct traversal is [:NEXT {name:"Station A}] because the node prior to B is the node with the name "Station A"

Ultimately, I need to return a chain of an indefinite length.  At each step of the graph, the correct path to take is determined by a value on the previous node.  How can I achieve this with a Cypher Query?

Thank you

I tried the following:

MATCH (a:Station { name: 'Station A' })((:Station)-[:NEXT {name:a.name}]->(:Station)){1,}(a:Station))
RETURN *

But get the following error
`From within a quantified path pattern, one may only reference variables, that are already bound in a previous` MATCH`clause.`

Comment: 1. Your last query is trying to find a loop from a back to a, and requires all `NEXT` relationships to have the same name value. Is that your actual use case (it does not conform to your stated rules)? And it has an extra right parenthesis at the end of the pattern. 2. Since the starting station has no "previous node", how does one pick the `NEXT` to use (if we want to follow your stated rules)? 3. Can you explain why you designed your `NEXT` relationships in this way? There may be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your question, you seem to describe the following, where you only want to return paths that follow the green arrow:

[image: follow the green arrow 1]

Doing this requires comparing a relationship with a node from a previous iteration. You can do this with a [predicate function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/):

```
MATCH p = (:Station {name: 'A'}) ((n)-[r:LINK]-(:Station))+
WHERE all(i IN range(0, size(r) - 2) WHERE n[i].name = r[i+1].name)
RETURN p
```

But reading your second query, maybe you meant something more like this:

[image: follow the green arrow 2]

In which case this query will work:

```
MATCH (a {name: 'A'})
MATCH p = (a)-[{name: a.name}]->+()
RETURN p
```

As the error message you got suggested, the first node variable `a` needs to be bound in a previous `MATCH` clause.

Comment: I can't inline the images till I have enough points! Accept my answer and I'll improve it 